# JS return label background color

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, label

here's my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="2.png" />
        <div id="colorChange"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="colorChoice">
        <form id="colorChoiceForm">
            <ul id="colorListParent">
                <li class="noButton">
                    <input type="radio" name="colorGroup" value="aaa12" id="aaa12" />
                    <label style="background-color:#d21212" class="colorPick" for="aaa12"></label>
                </li>
                <li class="noButton">
                    <input type="radio" name="colorGroup" value="daaa" id="daaa"/>
                    <label style="background-color:#202020" class="colorPick" for="daaa"></label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>>
</body>
```

and JS:

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("colorListParent").addEventListener("click", function(e){
        var bgrColor = (e.target.style.backgroundColor); 
        console.log(bgrColor);
        console.log(typeof bgrColor);
        document.getElementById("colorChange").style.backgroundColor = bgrColor;
    });
}

window.onload = load;
```

Until I binded labels with buttons with for/id script worked - bby that I mean background color of #colorChange changed to color of clicked label. 
Now var bgrColor returns two strings - first one of them is color I need, but the second one is empty and color of #colorChange doesn't change.

Where's problem?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: @huanfeng, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ythv11to/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you start using label[for], you'll have to approach it in a different way because your "click" event will be fired twice - once for the label and once for the radio button (which gets selected automatically. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5so4uat6/) is a working fiddle and below is the changed JS code.

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("colorListParent").addEventListener("click", function(e){
        //alert(e.target.id);
        if(e.target.id) {
            var selector = 'label[for=' + e.target.id + ']';
            var label = document.querySelector(selector);
            var bgrColor = label.style.backgroundColor;
            //alert(bgrColor);
            //alert(typeof bgrColor);
            document.getElementById("colorChange").style.backgroundColor = bgrColor;
        }
    });
}

window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are clicking the label, the 'input' DOM element is clicked as well, so you basically have 2 'click' events.
try adding something like that:

```
        if(bgrColor && bgrColor.length>0){
            document.getElementById("colorChange").style.backgroundColor = bgrColor;
        }
```